# When a custom policy relying party includes both SignIn and Signup, is there any way to choose (or force) signup UI by default?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a SignUpOrSignin custom policy that is working well. I prefer not to change its xml definition.

There are scenarios where user need to register, and the default page the user sees must be the signup page. However, my my SignUpOrSignin custom policy shows SignIn page by default, and the user needs to click on the SignUp button, so policy UI changes to SignUp.

Is there any way to change the default page of my SignUpOrSignin policy based on what user needs to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
    <ClaimsProviderSelections>      
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSignUp"/>
    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSignUp" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Ok, so to make sure my understanding, I need to split the <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn"> into two UserJourney , one for SignUp and the other SignIn, and Signup  will look like your XML snippet?

Comment: Yes - that will do it.

Comment: Is there any way to change the authorize URL query string so that it jumps to the SignUp page?

Comment: No, you have to have two RP, one for each journey.